# Calculating ObjectAtIndex items in tableview

Tags: arrays, uitableview, calculated-columns, operation

I have an array which contains my product prices.They are number type on my pList. I can reach them with this code.

```
[[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Adi"];
```

I can show these items with my cell view. But I want to summarise the items and set my Total label.text

For Example :

```
[[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Adi"] = 55 in my plist value.
```

another :

```
[[mainList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Adi"] = 45 in my pList value.
```

I want to summarise items like `first one + second one = my total`.
`55+45 = 100 $`

It should summarise my `first row item + my second row item`.

How can I calculate those items ?

Thank you very much !

Edited...

I tried these codes ;

```
for (int i=0; i<[mainList count]; i++) {


        int a=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"dAdi"] integerValue];

        int b=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"dAdi"] integerValue];

    int final = a + b;

    self.lblToplamTutar.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",final];
```

it doesnt work correctly.

Ok. I found the solution.

There is the method for summarise array objects.

```
-(void)toplamaYap{

int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i < [mainList count]; i++)
{
    sum += [[[mainList objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"dAdi"] intValue];
}
self.lblToplamTutar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
 }
```

Thank you for replies. Especially Santi Bernaldo...

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting these values from your plist, I assume you are receiving `NSNumber` values, type of object for getting numbers values allowed with `Plist serialization`.

So sending the `message` "integerValue" to your `NSNumber` objects:

```
int i=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Adi"] integerValue];

int j=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"Adi"] integerValue];

int final = i + j;

self.totalLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",final];
```

Comment: it doesnt work. totalLabel.text = 0
it should summ first row + second row 
those codes summation itself. like this; first row value = 55 final = 110 i want to summation firstrow + secondrow value.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now "i" is taking the value of row 1, and "j" the value of row 2

Comment: Thank you for answer Santi.. I have 10+ object in my array. How can i use for loop for that ?
I tried ;
    `for (int a=0; a<=mainList.count; a++) {`
        
        `int i=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:a] objectForKey:@"dAdi"]` `integerValue];`
        
        `int j=[[[mainList objectAtIndex:a+1] objectForKey:@"dAdi"]` `integerValue];`
        
        `int final = i + j;`
        
        `self.lblToplamTutar.text=[NSString` `stringWithFormat:@"%i",final];`

    `}`
doesnt work. There is the NSLOG : [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

Comment: Change your "for" line for this "for (int a=0; a<[mainList count]; a++)". You were using an index that beyonds the array bounds. Don't forget send the message "count" to the array. And please mark my answer as correct if it was. Cheers

Comment: it doesnt work again. still same problem. [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]' I think my j integer `objectAtIndex:a+1` is creating a problem. for loop starting with 1 it should start with 0. are there any codes to change a++ ??

Comment: Of course, delete the plus sign, iterate over only "a" not "a+1"

Comment: You are trying to get an object from the array that doesn't exists

Comment: Have you printed in the console the values you are obtaining? F.e.: NSLog(@"%i",i);

Comment: I updated my question again. I found the solution. Thank you for trying to help me Santi !